# Facebook open graph tutorial not working correctly and not running without chrome

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I was trying the open graph tutorial from Facebook developers site.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/

I copied and pasted the code and changed the app ID with mine. Step 2 worked fine, but from step 4 meta tags are not working. I checked the code several times,app ID and "YOUR_NAMESPACE"is changed correctly. I was developing inside **localhost** of ***WAMP*** server. Did I miss anything? I followed every step from the tutorial.

Secondly 'Add to timeline' or 'login' box isn't showing in any browser except chrome. Inside chrome it works fine, but  in firefox or IE it shows only a link to Facebook site. Why is that!

And suggest me some good tutorial on open graph.Please Help!

Comment: Need more information to answer this question.  What are your tags, how are you trying to access the login - are they different user accounts in IE and FF? Are those accounts Devs on the app? Is your app in sandbox mode?  We need more information before we can give you a meaningful response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably didn't work as it says the object page in Step 4 has to be publicly accessible. Facebook needs to be able to gather data from that page to present in time line. Your localhost mamp install won't be publicly accessible.

From the tutorial >>

> ```
> Before being able to publish an Open Graph action for a user and having define its
> corresponding connected object type in Step 3, you will now need to create a publicly
> accessible web page that represents this object using Open Graph metatags. Once this 
> object page is created, you can use the Graph API to publish an action.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen any good tutorials on it besides facebook's. They go in depth into every aspect of it as it is their product. I followed that same tutorial and it works perfectly.

Without your code I cant really help. If you put your meta tags up ill have a look.

Im also not sure if it actually works off the local host.